# Proof - Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $q_n$ be the number of words of length n in the alphabed $\{a, b, c, d\}$ that contains an odd number of b's.

1. Prove that for all $n \geq 0$, then $q_{n+1} = 4^n + 2 *q_n \tag{1}\label{eq1}$
2. Deduce that $q_n = \frac{4^n - 2^n}{2}$

My approach in solving this question is in \eqref{eq1},i divide and conquer in that i consider some-words that begin with a b or not. Somehow the approach makes sense but i cant seem to gain the traction to solve it.

In the second part however, i decided to go for induction.

I've solved quite a number of induction examples but i dont know why this task seems a bit unique to think through. I even thought of using probability but it seems like a long shot in hindsight

Comment: You obviously have a typo in $2$.  $\frac {16 - 2^n}2$ is negative if $n > 4$.

Comment: And 1) is obviously false.  $q_0 = 0$ and $q_1 = 1$ and $1 = q_1 \ne 4 + 2*q_0 = 4 + 2*0 =4$.

Comment: But if you have proven 1) then proving 2) by induction is just a matter of prove $q_0 = \frac {4^2 - 2^0}2$ and that $q_{n+1} = 4^n + 2*q_n = 4^n + 2(\frac {4^2 - 2^n}2) = \frac {4^2 - 2^{n+1}}2$.  Just do it.  It's all set up for you. (although you have obviously written the problem incorrectly as none of those are true.)

Comment: Sorry. Yess i had a typo at $4^2$ i changed it to t $4^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I)

There are $4^n$ $n$ letter words.  If $q_n$ of them have an odd number of $b$s then $4^n - q_n$ have an even number of $b$s.

For each $n$ letter word with an odd number of $b$s, we can create $3$ possible $n+1$ letter words with an odd number of $b$s by adding $a,c$ or $d$ to the end.  There are $3*q_n$ such words we can make this way.

For each $n$ letter word with an even number of $b$s, we can create a $n+1$ letter word with an odd number of $b$ by adding $b$ to the end.  This is $4^n - q_n$ such words we can make this way.

That accounts for all $n+1$ letter words with an odd number of $b$s.  (Each $n+1$ letter word is a $n$ letter word with a letter added to the end.  So this is sufficient to account for all possible $n+1$ letter words with an odd number of $b$s.)

And there are $q_{n+1} = 3*q_n + 4^n - q_n = 4^n + 2*q_n$ such words.

II)

Base step: $q_1  = 1$.  There is exactly one, $1$ letter word with an odd number of $b$s.  It is "$b$".

Induction step:
suppose $q_n = \frac {4^n - 2^n}2$ and we know from I) that  $q_{n+1} = 4^n + 2*q_n = 4^n + 2(\frac {4^n-2^n}2)$ then

$q_{n+1} =4^n + 2*q_n = $
$4^n + 2(\frac {4^2-2^n}2) = $

$4^n + 4^n - 2^n = $

$2*4^n - 2^n = $

$\frac {4*4^n - 2*2^n}2 = $

$\frac {4^{n+1} - 2^{n+1}}2$

That's it.